# Jquery form validation - telephone number

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have setup jQuery validation on form, The validation currently tests that the telephone number field isn't empty and is a number, but I'd like it to be able to handle a user placing a space after the mobile/area code.

Can anyone advise what i'd need to do to allow this?

This is my current code -

```
if((phone.length == 0) || (names == 'Please Enter Your Contact Number (no space)')){  
        var error = true;  
        $('.error').fadeIn(500);  
        $('.pStar').fadeIn(500);

    }else{  
        var value = $('#phone').val().replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
        var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
        if(!intRegex.test(value)) {
             var error = true;  
             $('.error').fadeIn(500);  
            $('.pStar').fadeIn(500);

        } else{
        $('.pStar').fadeOut(500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some valid/invalid inputs ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) rather than re-inventing the wheel

a quick google search for uk numbers with jquery validate turned this up

[filters](https://github.com/johnantoni/jquery.validate.filters)

that looks like this

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function(phone_number, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
  phone_number.match(/^(\(?(0|\+44)[1-9]{1}\d{1,4}?\)?\s?\d{3,4}\s?\d{3,4})$/);
  }, 'Please specify a valid phone number'
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex to validate phone numbers.

```
var pattern = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;  
if(!$('#phone').val().test(elementValue)){
    //Invalid number
}
```

This regex will optionally accept starting `(` or ending `)` for area code and will optionally accept `-` after first 3 digits after area code.

Comment: Yes it is mostly for US number but will validate other phone number formats also with little or no change because `()` and `-` are optional.

Comment: First, your code is wrong. where have you used the pattern in validation?
you are testing value against value but not against the regex