# Validation for numbers and email Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

I am looking to do some validation inside my jquery script for numbers and email. I am unsure how i can add this to my current script? This is what i have so far:

```
<script>      
       $("#quote-me").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();  
         var pnum = $("#partnum").val();
         var quantity = $("#quant").val();
         var location = $("#locate").val();
         var custemail = $("#email").val();

         var r = $.ajax({

            url : "/support/quote/",
            dataType : "JSON",
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                action : "true",
                pnum : pnum,
                quantity : quantity,
                location : location,
                custemail : custemail
            }
        });
        r.done(function(response){
            if(response.confirm !== undefined) {

                $("#confirmmessage").html(response.confirm);
                $("#confirmmessage").show(); 
                $("#speedquoteform input[type='text']").val("");
             }

        });
         });

         $("#speedquoteform input[type='text']").focusin(function() {
            if($("#confirmmessage").is(":visible")) { 
                $("#confirmmessage").hide(); 
            }

         });

    </script>
```

Comment: Validation of email address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855865/jquery-regex-validation-of-e-mail-address

Comment: Validation of phone number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262942/jquery-form-validation-telephone-number

Comment: Are you asking how to do the validation or where to place the code? If the first, what are your conditions? If the second, then the answer is after your call to e.preventDefault() and before you make your r = $.ajax() assignment.

Comment: This question has absolutely nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Edited tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.isNumeric()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) to check if a variable is a number:

```
quantity.isNumeric();  // assuming 'quantity' is what you intend to validate
```