# Phone number validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I have this really cool validation script for entering currency which I love

[Demo Currency Validator](https://jsfiddle.net/938ewm3v/)

```
$("#saleprice").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

But I would love to have the same thing to validate a phone number. Here is my fiddle with the regex for a phone, but I cant seem to get it to work. The code is not allowing any characters to be typed in even though I specify characters like `()` as well as numbers and `-`,`.` to be allowed in the regex.

[Demo Telephone Validator](https://jsfiddle.net/o10t9eqL/)

```
$("#telephone").on("keyup", function(){
    var valid = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/.test(this.value),
        val = this.value;

    if(!valid){
        console.log("Invalid input!");
        this.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
    }
});
```

I would like to allow the following formats of a phone number.

- (123) 456 7899
- (123).456.7899
- (123)-456-7899
- 123-456-7899
- 123 456 7899
- 1234567899

Comment: Do you actually have a question here?

Comment: It appears that the first one validates AS you type! Consider you typing 123.45; 1, 12, 123, 123., 123.4, 123.45 are all valid. But with the phone number string, you don't really have valid partials, so you'd need to do a final validation pass on blur/enter, also?

Comment: @arkascha I said in the post "But I would love to have the same thing to validate a phone number...but I cant seem to get it to work"

Comment: Arguably not a question ;) but I agree that the question is implicit. On topic, see if these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262942/jquery-form-validation-telephone-number

Comment: "Does not work" has never helped anyone, anywhere at any time to solve a problem or get an answer. Please specify what that means. Is no validation done? Is the validation wrong? To much rejected? Too much accepted? What is the sequence that cause you to say "is not working"? _Be specific_! Without that you expect us to find out. _Why?_

Comment: you can use input mask.. http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: ok fine it's not a question but it is arguably a statement which "obviously" contains a meaning which implies that I am referring to code that is not working so I obviously need help for it to work. I will edit my post.

Comment: _I would like to allow the following formats of a phone number,_ but so far it ...

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP awesome! I am going to try it.

Comment: @CesarBielich Tried allowing only last option ? e.g.; `1234567899`  ten consecutive numbers ? , formatting to include `-` or `()`  after `1234567899` input ?

Comment: vote my answer...(y)

Comment: Also try this too. http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: @NithinKrishnanP works perfect and simple. Make it an answer and Ill vote it

Comment: So I am buggered with my phone number. ie +44.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A better way is to use `jquery input masks`.Also you can customize the
>   `input mask`..

Follow the links

1.[**masking 1**](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

2.[**masking 2**](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: love this thing, already changed a ton on my site to use this. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `input` element `maxlength` to `10` ; replace non-digit characters ; format value when `input` length is ten characters

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, "");
  if (e.target.value.length === 10) {
    // do stuff
    var ph = e.target.value.split("");
    ph.splice(3, 0, "-"); ph.splice(7, 0, "-");
    $("label").html(ph.join(""))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="tel: input ten numbers" />
<label for="input"></label>
```